# How to select specific entry widgets for function calls in tkinter using a touch screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, touch

I am creating a touchscreen GUI with multiple entry widgets that are edited using a keypad. How can I know which entry widget the user selected? I've created a roundabout way where each entry is coded as a button and when clicked, the button edits a 'selected' variable that the keypad then uses to know which to edit but is there a better way? Possibly using focus? (I have the button widgets working but I want to use the commented entry widget, also some irrelevant code has been deleted so the post wasn't overly long)

```
class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        self.shared_data = {
            'codeOne' : StringVar(),
            'codeTwo' : StringVar(), 
            'selectedCode' : StringVar(),
        }

    def setCode(self, value):
        #function updates selected variable
        selectedVar = self.shared_data['selectedCode']
        if selectedVar.get() == 'codeOne':
            code = self.shared_data['codeOne']
        elif selectedVar.get() == 'codeTwo':
            code = self.shared_data['codeTwo']
        else: #non selected
            print('nothing selected')
            return False
        old = code.get()
        if type(value) == int:
            code.set(old+str(value))
        else:
            code.set(old[0:len(old)-1])
        return True

    def setVariable(self, variable, value):
        variable.set(value)
        return True

class MenuPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        Label(self, text="Code 1:", font='Helvetica 15').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=E, pady=10)
        Button(self, textvariable=controller.shared_data['codeOne'], font=MENU_ENTRIES, width=7, bg='grey99', command=lambda:controller.setVariable(controller.shared_data['selectedCode'],'codeOne')).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)
        #Entry(self,  textvariable=controller.shared_data['codeOne'], font='Helvetica 15').grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=1, pady=10, sticky=W)

        Label(self, text="Code 2:", font='Helvetica 15').grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=E, pady=10)
        Button(self, textvariable=controller.shared_data['codeTwo'], font=MENU_ENTRIES, width=7, bg='grey99', command=lambda:controller.setVariable(controller.shared_data['selectedCode'],'codeTwo')).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)
        #Entry(self, textvariable=controller.shared_data['codeTwo'], font='Helvetica 15').grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=3, pady=10, sticky=W)

        Button(self, text="1", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(1)).grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=2, padx=(20,5), pady=10)
        Button(self, text="2", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(2)).grid(row=1, column=4, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        Button(self, text="3", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(3)).grid(row=1, column=5, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        Button(self, text="4", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(4)).grid(row=3, column=3, rowspan=2, padx=(20,5), pady=10)
        Button(self, text="5", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(5)).grid(row=3, column=4, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        Button(self, text="6", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(6)).grid(row=3, column=5, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        Button(self, text="7", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(7)).grid(row=5, column=3, rowspan=2, padx=(20,5), pady=10)
        Button(self, text="8", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(8)).grid(row=5, column=4, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        Button(self, text="9", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(9)).grid(row=5, column=5, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        Button(self, text="DELETE", width=7, command=lambda:controller.setCode('delete')).grid(row=7, column=3, rowspan=2, columnspan=2, padx=(20,5), pady=10)
        Button(self, text="0", width=3, command=lambda:controller.setCode(0)).grid(row=7, column=5, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)

 app = MyApp()
 app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it would work exactly the same is if you had a traditional mouse and keyboard. When the user touches an entry widget, that widget gets focus. Your function simply needs to input text into the widget with the focus. This is exactly the sort of problem that the concept of "focus" exists.

Delete your buttons, put your Entry widgets back, and change `setCode` to be this:

```
def setCode(self, value):
    # get the widget with the focus
    widget = self.focus_get()

    # insert the value
    widget.insert("insert", value)
```

You  might also want to give the first entry widget focus. To do that you need to keep a reference to it (it's a best practice to separate the creation of the widget from adding it to the window with `grid`, `pack` or `place` even if you don't need a reference):

```
entry = Entry(self, textvariable=controller.shared_data['codeOne'], width=7, bg='grey99')
entry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)
entry.focus_set()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to edit the insert function for when the delete key is pressed but aside from that, it works!